# Set_error_handler with static-method callback

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I `RTM` but I couldn't find any nice answer to this question, so here is it:

- Can I call a static
  method as an error handler (for example: `set_error_handler('error::function')`)?
- Is it recommended?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/set_error_handler) expects a value of the [pseudo-type *callback*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback). And in the examples there you can see that there are two ways to specify a static method:

```
set_error_handler(array('Class', 'method'));

// since PHP 5.2.3
set_error_handler('Class::method');
```

Comment: What if a have an autoload function for classes and the class in class::method is not yet included? Does PHP autoload it?

Comment: @Charlie Pigarelli: I don’t know. Why don’t you try it?

Comment: Note that using self::method doesn't work. The Class name must be specified.

Comment: If you are using PHP namespaces be sure to include the full namespace to your class.  I.e. set_error_handler('MyNameSpaceRoot\MyNameSpacePath\MyErrorClass::myErrorHandlerMethod'); or in the other form: set_error_handler(array('MyNameSpaceRoot\MyNameSpacePath\MyErrorClass', 'myErrorHandlerMethod'));

Comment: Note that if you are using a namespace, include it in the actual string; a "use" statement will have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; this syntax works:

```
set_error_handler('error::function');
```

As stated in the doc, you just have to pass a valid callback. <s>`http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback`</s>(dead link)